# JavaFX and IntelliJ Error: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I started a new JavaFX application with the JavaFX project template that IntelliJ gives you that will only display a GUI created with Scene Builder with some line charts, as far as I'm concerned, the code is right and simple, it's just a test project.

Also, I can't visualize the .class file in IntelliJ

The message is:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: C:\Users\pv3\Desktop\PruebasFX_OracleFXProyectInicio\target\classes
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: GraficasVentPrueba1.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)
    
Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;


public class GraficasVentPrueba1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException{
        FXMLLoader launcherGraficas = new FXMLLoader(GraficasVentPrueba1.class.getResource("GraficasVentPrueba1.fxml"));
        Scene emergenteGraficas = new Scene(launcherGraficas.load());
        stage.setScene(emergenteGraficas);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

It supposed to just open the .fxml. Instead it shows that error message

Comment: the last line of the error tells you what's wrong :) btw: better format the error as code to make it easily readable

Comment: Study [packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html) and [understand the module system](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## *Java Platform Module System*

In your error message, *unnamed package not allowed in module* is the key here.

Check your `module-info.java` file created by the JavaFX project template in IntelliJ. Be sure to edit that file to keep up with changes you make.

I would guess that you changed the names of your classes and/or packages but did not edit your `module-info.java` file to suit.

Tip: When changing names of classes and packages in your app in IntelliJ, use IntelliJ’s *Refactor* features. When doing so, the `module-info.java` file should be automatically updated. See manual on [*Rename refactorings*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/rename-refactorings.html)

When using JavaFX, you must learn about the [*Java Platform Module System*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System). While optional for some other kinds of Java apps, compliance with Java modularity is required of [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) apps.

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74879669/javafx-and-intellij-error-java-lang-module-invalidmoduledescriptorexception/74882178#comment132147002_74879669), for working with JavaFX, you must understand both Java packages and Java modules. Resources include:

- [*Packages*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html) (tutorial by Oracle)
- [Understanding Java 9 Modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html), article by Paul Deitel.
- A few books including [*The Java Module System*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/40224336-the-java-module-system) by Nicolai Parlog.